# search a name in dataset error :Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'

Tags: matlab

I load a file which has some columns with data.The first line contains ,CITY,YEAR2000 .

The first column  has name of cities.The other columns contain number data.

I am trying to search for a specific city using:

```
data(data.CITY=='Athens',3:end)
```

where

`data = dataset('File','cities.txt','Delimiter',',')`

but I receive an error

```
Undefined function 'eq' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

--------UPDATE-----------------------------

Ok, use :

```
data(find(strncmp(data.CITY,'Athens',length('Athens'))),3:end)
```

Comment: Do you have the Statistics Toolbox installed? What do you get if you do `help dataset`?

Comment: @Eitan T:I updated.yes,i get the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried with using `strncmp` tangled with `find`?

I would use it this way

```
find(strncmp(data.CITY,'ATHENS',length('ATHENS')))
```

**EDIT**

Other opportunities to exploit would encompass `strfind`

```
strfind(data.CITY,'ATHENS')
```

**EDIT 2**

You could also try with

```
data(ismember(data.CITY,'ATHENS'),3:end)
```

This should lead you to the results you expect (at least I guess so).

**EDIT 3**
Given your last request I would go for this solution:

```
inp = input('Name of the CITY: ','s')
Name of the City: ATHENS
data(find(strncmp(data.CITY,inp,length(inp))),3:end)
```

Comment: :And how I will use it to sgow columns 3:end ?

Comment: :Ok , i figured it.Thanks a lot!

Comment: :One more please if you can.I am taking from user input the name of the city. city=input(...) and then trying to do  "data(find(strncmp(data.CITY,'city',length('city'))),3:end)" but i am receiving an empty cell .How can I do this?Thanks

Comment: :Ok ,thanks a lot!I just figured to use also ' data.CITY,eval(input).

Comment: :Sorry to bother again!Last one!From the user input now, i receive the year but as string because I have to use 'Y2000'.So either trying "data.eval('year')" either "data(find(strncmp(data.CITY.inp,length(inp)))" it doesn't work . It works like "data.Y200".That is I am trying to accomplish.

Comment: :Ok , i found it "result=data(:,{'CITY',eval('input')});". But now I can't find how to use min. If I use "min(data.Y200)" it works but I want to use the user input , so "min(data.input)" or "min(data.eval(input))" don't work!I think this is the last one.Sorry but you see I am in a hurry!